# Counting Rows Once In Range Which Contain Data

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to figure out a formula that will count each row in a range, that contains any cell that is not empty. For example

```
      Item 1|Item 2|Item 3
Cat 1   X      X      X
Cat 2
Cat 3   X      X      X
```

And

```
      Item 1|Item 2|Item 3
Cat 1   X              
Cat 2
Cat 3                 X
```

Should both return 2. I know I could use a helper column with `COUNTIF(Row,"<>")` then use `COUNTIF(Column,">0")`, but I'm trying to avoid doing that because it will create other issues. Is there a way to do what I want all in one formula?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on the version of Excel:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--((B2:B4&C2:C4&D2:D4)<>""))
```

Swap `SUMPRODUCT()` for `SUM()` if on ms365.

Comment: Knew there had to be a super simple way to do it I just couldn't figure out. Much appreciate.

Answer (score 1):

An obviously **much** longer formula but, for larger data ranges, less time-consuming to construct, as it doesn't involve selecting each column individually:

```
=ROWS(B2:P6)-SUM(INT(MMULT(--ISBLANK(B2:P6),TRANSPOSE(COLUMN(B2:P6)/COLUMN(B2:P6)))/COLUMNS(B2:P6)))
```

(as an array formula, this runs in Excel 2007 and later, although it could be shortened a lot in Office 365)

[image: Screenshot illustrating proposed formula]